# Early Sources that Charity Should Optimally Support Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, tzedakah-charity

What are the earliest sources that state that charity ought to optimally be used to support Torah study. I.e. if one can choose various charitable causes to support, that s/he should choose to donate towards Torah study. (Looking particularly for pre-18th century sources).

Comment: Over poor people??

Comment: @DoubleAA Over any charitable cause including poor people.

Comment: Can you cite that such a position exists at all, that we should search for early predecessors?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have heard it repeatedly in the name of poskim, and I myself heard it from a posek although I wont name him because I am (as you may have guessed) somewhat skeptical. I do know somewhat of a source in the Prisha's interpretation of "gadol talmud torah yoser meihatzalas nefashos" which is that one should contribute towards Torah study rather than towards saving lives (e.g. of captives who will be killed). However, the Taz and all the other poskim I saw write that this is a tragic and complete mistake.

Comment: Just to clarify (since you say "Over any charitable cause including poor people"), you're discussing donating money to non-poor Torah scholars, in order to... provide for luxuries??

Comment: I heard from a rabbi I highly respect that the Ramban writes that the purpose of the institution of *maaser kesafim* (tithing income) was to help Torah scholars. I'd have to search for the actual quotation.

Comment: @msh210 one could (theoretically) choose to support a Torah institution e.g. a kollel whose members would otherwise support themselves. Or one could choose to support the poor who are failing to earn a sufficient livelihood even with effort.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Rambam says the complete opposite, and condensed those that learn Torah and rely on the charity of others to make a living.

Comment: @yechezkel "*condensed* those that learn Torah" ?

Comment: @mevaqesh condemns.

Comment: @yechezkel in Hil. Talmud Torah he specifically criticized those who shunt themselves onto the congregation to be supported, refuse to work, then plunder the charity funds. His statement there doesnt reveal what he would hold about being supported by someone *voluntarily*. Since Rambam himself was supported by his brother while he learned all day (as he writes is a responsum in the Blau ed.) we can certainly assume that he held that this wasn't forbidden. There is evidence for this from Hil. Matnos Ani'yim where he praises those who support their sons or daughters (!) whom they are not...

Comment: @yechezkel required to support so that they can learn Torah. It is regarding such an arrangement that we can inquire whether it is better to support them or poor people. Furthermore, there are those who disagree with thi view of the Rambam. See for example Kessef Mishne to Hil. Talmud Torah thereon.